# What is the difference between Worker and ListenableWorker in WorkManager?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I go through this link [Migrating from Firebase JobDispatcher to WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb) ,

I found there is **Worker** and **ListenableWorker**, where to use these both? any advantage on using any one of them?

**Worker :**

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.work.Data;
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker.Result;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

class MyWorker extends Worker {

  public MyWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
    super(appContext, params);
  }

  @Override
  public ListenableWorker.Result doWork() {
    // Do your work here.
    Data input = getInputData();

    // Return a ListenableWorker.Result
    Data outputData = new Data.Builder()
        .putString(“Key”, “value”)
        .build();
    return Result.success(outputData);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStopped() {
    // Cleanup because you are being stopped.
  }
}
```

**ListenableWorker:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker;
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker.Result;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

class MyWorker extends ListenableWorker {

  public MyWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
    super(appContext, params);
  }

  @Override
  public ListenableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result> startWork() {
    // Do your work here.
    Data input = getInputData();

    // Return a ListenableFuture<>
  }

  @Override
  public void onStopped() {
    // Cleanup because you are being stopped.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Worker`s run synchronously on a background thread.  `ListenableWorker`s are expected to run asynchronously - they are invoked on the main thread and you are supposed to offer all the threading (such as moving them to a background thread).  `Worker`s are simpler and are expected to be the basic building block of your app.  You can read more about them here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker

If you're interested, you can also check out `CoroutineWorker` and `RxWorker`.